# access data in our main activity By socket communication using primus-android library

Tags: android, sockets, primus

I m using primus-android (https://github.com/cine-io/primus-android) to communicate with a socket. In the library, I m getting string data. But I can't get it in my java file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling datacallback as mentioned in the document of Github file, by using WebSocket call back, access on string available function, which will lead to access data coming in the socket.